# Cargar datos alojados en sql, a 2 tablas en php

Tags: php, sql-server

necesito cargar datos en 2 tablas, los datos están en la misma tabla alojada en sql server.

Les dejo las lineas de codigo que estoy implementando pero tengo problemas para visualizar los datos

```
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>IdUsuario</td>
        <td>[Cédula]</td>
        <td>[Nombre]</td>
        
    </tr>
    <?php if(!$res) {?>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="6">No hay datos para mostrar</td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    else {
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row['idUsuario'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['Cedula'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['Nombre'];?></td>
        
    </tr>
   
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        
        <td>[Apellido]</td>
        <td>[Teléfono]</td>
        <td>[Email]</td>
    </tr>
    <?php if(!$res) {?>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="6">No hay datos para mostrar</td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    else {
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {?>
    <tr>
         
         <td><?php echo $row['Apellido'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['Telefono'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['Email'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }//Fin while
    }//Fin if
    sqlsrv_close($con); ?>
</table>
        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Aparte de que se muestran dos tablas, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: en la segunda tabla no cargan los datos apellido, telefono, email

Comment: Entonces es probable que el error esté en la consulta y esa no la incluiste en el código. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregarla.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puedes hacer esto dos veces:

```
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
```

Es preciso entender una cosa cuando trabajas con resultados de consultas: lo que obtienes (en `$res`)  es un conjunto de resultados, algo así como un puntero que luego puedes recorrer mediante alguno de los métodos `fetch_`. Lo que ocurre cuando aplicas esto: `while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {` es que mueves el puntero dentro del bucle para obtener los datos desde la primera hasta la última fila y cuando el bucle termina **ya no hay más datos en el puntero**. De modo que cuando intentas un segundo `while` para construir la segunda tabla, ya no hay datos en `$res`, porque fueron leídos en el primer `while`.

Conociendo esto, puedes construir dos variables distintas dentro de un único `while` y luego agregar cada variable en su tabla respectiva.

Por ejemplo:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    /*
        La mezcla de código PHP/HTML es poco flexible
        para casos como este no ayuda para nada
        vamos a trabajar las tablas con variables
        dentro de un único bloque PHP
        el código queda más claro y es más flexible
        Para ello creamos de entrada dos variables para cada tabla
    */          
    $tableOne=
    "<table>
        <tr>
            <td>IdUsuario</td>
            <td>[Cédula]</td>
            <td>[Nombre]</td>
            
        </tr>";
        
    $tableTwo=
    "<table>
        <tr>
            
            <td>[Apellido]</td>
            <td>[Teléfono]</td>
            <td>[Email]</td>
        </tr>";     
    if(!$res) {
        /*
            En ese caso $noData servirá para las dos tablas
        */
        $noData=
        "<tr>
             <td colspan=\"3\">No hay datos para mostrar</td>
        </tr>";
        /*
            Agregamos $noData a ambas tablas y cerramos
        */
        $tableOne.="$noData</table>";
        $tableTwo.="$noData</table>";
        
    }
    else {
        /* Creamos dos variables para recoger las filas por separado*/
        $rowsOne="";
        $rowsTwo="";
        while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
            /*
                Estamos concatenando entre comillas dobles
                por lo que es permitido en este caso referirse a los
                índices de arrays sin comillas
            */
            $rowsOne.="
            <tr>
                 <td>$row[idUsuario]</td>
                 <td>$row[Cedula]</td>
                 <td>$row[Nombre]</td>
            </tr>";
            $rowsTwo.="
            <tr>
                 <td>$row[Apellido]</td>
                 <td>$row[Telefono]</td>
                 <td>$row[Email]</td>
            </tr>";
        }
        /*
            Agregamos cada grupo de filas a su tabla y cerramos
        */
        $tableOne.="$rowsOne</table>";
        $tableTwo.="$rowsTwo</table>";
    }
    sqlsrv_close($con);
    /*
        Imprimimos ambas tablas
    */
    echo $tableOne;
    echo $tableTwo; 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores en tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar el mismo juego de resultados dos veces, debes prepararlo desde la consulta, enviando un arreglo de opciones para crear un *cursor* que te permita "navegar" entre los resultados:

```
// Suponiendo que no tienes filtros
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
// Vacío porque no hay filtros
$params = [];
// Crear cursor para poder manipular el apuntador en conjunto de resultados
$options = ["Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED];
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);

// Recorres los resultados por primera vez
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    // Aquí creas la primera tabla
}
```

En este punto, se terminaron los resultados y no puedes recorrer nuevamente el conjunto hasta que coloques el apuntador nuevamente al inicio:

```
// Ahora reinicia el apuntador del juego de resultados
sqlsrv_fetch($res, SQLSRV_SCROLL_ABSOLUTE, -1);

// Otra vez recorres los resultados
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    // Aquí creas la segunda tabla
}
```

### Referencias:

- [PHP sqlsrv_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php)
- [Tipos de cursor sqlsrv](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) en inglés
- [PHP sqlsrv_fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php)